# Quantum Mechanics Testability

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistics

Statistics by their very nature are not definitive in their predictions for single events. We can say the probability of getting heads on a coin flip is 1/2, yet we can flip a 1000 coins and they could all come up tails. How many coins would it take to disprove the 1/2 prediction? So isn’t QM in the same situation? How can it be accurate if it can’t predict with certainty a given event?

Comment: Why do you believe that QM is in the same situation?

Comment: Doesn’t it use probabilities in its equations?

Comment: I imagine it would take all coins in the universe to never flip heads for all eternity for the 1/2 probability to be wrong.

Comment: It would take one half of the coins plus one

Comment: The fact that $1000$ tosses give tails does not disprove anything. It is in perfect agreement with classical probability to have repeatedly the same event. It is simply *improbable*, not impossible. Your line of reasoning is difficult to follow, at least by me.

Comment: My point is when a theory is based on probabilities it become a difficult if not impossible theory to disprove.

Comment: @Lambda are you aware of the law of large numbers?

Comment: The law of large numbers is based on probabilities. So it’s kind of like using probabilities to prove probabilities. I don’t doubt what you’re saying my point is when a theory uses probabilities it shields the theory from close scrutiny.

Comment: *"So isn’t QM in the same situation? How can it be accurate if it can’t predict with certainty a given event?"* It's not clear what is meant by that sentence.

Comment: When a theory uses probability it allows for predictions to be wrong, but yet still considered to be right. On my coin flip example could I ever make a testable flip? Never. How could you ever prove me wrong? That’s my point.

Comment: @Lambda You should look up some philosophical background on the problem of induction -- you are substantially right, in that almost any outcome could just be a low-probability result in QM, but as a practical matter, the statistics of our world seem to agree with the predictions of QM. Viewpoints will vary, but it's better to think of scientific theories, imo, as "useful" rather than "true."

Comment: As there are no ideal experiments, every measurement comes with error bar and thus any physical theory is probabilistic when it's confronted with reality. So you "can't disprove" anything. From that you may start appreciating the value of your ideas

Comment: @Lambda no, LLN is a theorem based on *observations* of a probabilistic experiment should approach the expected value. So unless all coins never flip heads again, LLN says we should expect $\sim50\%$ distribution. Also, can you please use the @ convention for pinging someone? I can't tell if you're replying to me without you doing so.

Comment: @KyleKanos I hear what you’re saying. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @OON But you must admit there is a difference between a theory/prediction that says “this is likely to happen” vs “this will happen”

Comment: @Lambda again. All theories when applied to the real world say only "this is likely to happen" becayse we always operate with imperfect knowledge. Funny that you are not consistent in your radicalism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many independent measurements we are rescued by the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers). That is, it becomes exceedingly unlikely to measure such a skewed result as all tails from your example. Note that many phenomena that are described quantum mechanically involve a large number of objects (for example the number of nuclei in a sample in radio-active decay or the number of hydrogen atoms in a gas discharge lamp to measure spectra). So the answer to the question is: We can measure the probabilities of random events with sufficient precision if we do enough measurements.

Further, there are predictions that are not affected by the probabilistic nature of quantum mechanics: We know only with certain probabilities to which state an excited hydrogen atom will decay, but there are only certain discrete energy levels it can decay to, so independently of the relative brightness of the spectral lines, the presence and position of the spectral lines of some atom are prediction precisely by quantum mechanics.

---

To demonstrate the law of the large numbers specifically for your classical example of a repeated coin flip we can explicitly determine the probabilities of the outcomes. If $n$ is the number of heads that turns up if we throw the coin $N$ times, we get a binomial distribution (with $p = 1/2$):
$$P_N(n) = \binom{N}{n} p^n (1-p)^{N-n} = \binom{N}{n} \left(\frac 1 2\right)^N.$$
As you might know the binomial coefficients have a sharp peak around $n = N/2$, so the most likely results are the ones where the number of heads and tails is almost the same.

So how likely is the result, that $n = 0$ for $N=1000$? It is 
$$P_N(0) = \underbrace{\binom{1000}{0}}_{=\,1} \left(\frac 1 2\right)^{1000} = 2^{-1000}.$$
This number is so incredibly small, we cannot even begin to fathom it. If you had made one flip of coins every second since the beginning of the universe about $13 \cdot 10^9$ years ago, you would only have flipped the coins
$$m = 1\,\mathrm{s^{-1}} \cdot 13 \cdot 10^9\,\mathrm{y} \cdot 365.25\,\mathrm{\frac d y} \cdot 24\,\mathrm{\frac h d} \cdot 60 \,\mathrm{\frac{min}{h}} \cdot 60\,\mathrm{\frac{s}{min}} = 4.1 \cdot 10^{17} \approx 2^{58.5}$$
times. That is the probability that in one of those flips the all tails event occurred is still negligible at $mP_N(0) \approx 2^{-941}$.

We can even quantify how probable it is to achieve a result more than a certain amount off the even result. We cite the standard deviation of the binomial probability distribution, that, intuitively, is a measure for the width of the peak of the distribution (again for $p=1/2$):
$$ \sigma = \sqrt{Np(1-p)} = \sqrt{N}/2$$
So when $N$ gets large, the deviation will be of the scale of $\sqrt{N}$, in other words the relative offset from an even result will for the "average measurement" not be larger than $1/\sqrt{N}$, for $N=1000$ this is about $3\%$.

Comment: $2^{-1000}\sim10^{-301}$ which is near the lower limit of double precision numbers. That's kinda fathomable to me as a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a category error in your reasoning.

That a theory is probabilistic in the sense that it explicitely uses and produce probabilities, as quantum mechanics does, *does not imply* that the theory itself is in any way random.

The probabilist predictions of QM are not uncertain: they are very precise probability values. What is uncertain is what you get when using these probabilities to predict a measurement outcome, which of course is what is expected from a probability value. It's kind of the whole point of what a probability is.

So, in short, probabilities are a fine tool; that a theory uses this tool does not make it inaccurate. Statistical mechanics for example works very well.